# mvc NUNIT System.NotImplementedException : The Method or Operation is not Implemented

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit, vs-unit-testing-framework

having some problems with my NUnit. I have this TestFixture testing a model

model is like this:

```
public class Model
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public void myAction(MyDatabase db, string r, string i) {
        db.DataEmp.Add(new DataEmp{
            Id = this.Id,
            DateOfAction = DateTime.UtcNow,
            R = r,
            I = i
        });
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

My TestCase in NUnit

```
    [Test]
    public void Method_Test_Pass_myAction()
    {
        newModel.myAction(db,"R","I");

        Assert.That(db.DataEmp.FirstOrDefault(de => de.Id == newModel.Id), Is.Null);
    }
```

It's giving me a

> System.NotImplementedException : The method or operation is not implemented.

So I'm not sure what's wrong, as I instantiated the newModel at the Setup method. And the method is running well if run the app.
Thoughts are appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: Try sharing the stack trace you get for that NotImplementedException.

Comment: sorry, but how do i share the stack trace? I'm new to c# programming, pardon me if i'm kinda slow :)

Answer (score 2):

First try running it in Debug to see where you are throwing the exception,
my guess is something is wrong with your MyDatabase